# Detecting russian characters on a form in PHP

Tags: php

I have a site where people can submit links to sites about iPhone apps. The guy submits the application name, description, category and URL. This site has years and never received any constructive submission from a russian developer but, unfortunately it was discovered by russian spammers that annoys the hell out of me. Even with all measures against spam, as caption boxes, etc., some guys insist on sending porn russian stuff that has nothing to do with iPhone.

I would like to ban completely any URL or post that is done using russian characters. 
For URLs I have not much to do, except checking if the URL contains ".ru". But for descriptions, I would like to detect russian characters. How do I do that in PHP?

thanks.

Comment: http://www.weberdev.com/Print-Code-Example.php?ExampleID=4650&mode=color

Answer (score 78, accepted):

<s>Да очень просто</s> It is easy to do with UTF-8 regular expressions (assuming your site uses UTF-8 encoding):

```
function isRussian($text) {
    return preg_match('/[А-Яа-яЁё]/u', $text);
}
```

Comment: I tested all 3 methods. Yours is the one that works in my case. And I see by your name, that you are probably from there! :-) Thanks.

Comment: @Mike, almost, I'm Russian-speaking but not from Russia :)

Comment: Cool... I love those russian characters... it is a language that seems to be written in a mirror... :-)

Comment: Thanks. I also found it useful to do preg_match_all and count the number of Russian characters, and use that to get a percentage. Kind of quasi-Bayesian.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks. We already stop form submissions using a list of "ever growing" stop words, but suddenly we have been hit with dozens of junk emails containing Russian characters. This is short, sweet and works 100%!

Comment: Nice, but not an ideal solution. It means you have to save your php files as UTF8.

Comment: Not worked on php7, but solved: preg_match( '/^([а-яА-ЯЁё]+)$/u', $userName); from here https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417568/preg-match-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B

Answer (score 16):

According to the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php), since version 5.1.0 it has been possible to look for specific (writing) scripts in utf-8 PCRE regular expressions by using \p{language code}. For Rusian that is

```
preg_match( '/[\p{Cyrillic}]/u', $text);
```

There is a warning on the page:

> Matching characters by Unicode property is not fast, because PCRE has
>   to search a structure that contains data for over fifteen thousand
>   characters.

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting reference to PCRE/REGEX/UNICODE documentation. This answer has been the most useful for me.

Answer (score 3):

now.. this code is about 5 years old, and 'worked for me' back when I had a similar problem

```
function detect_cyr_utf8($content)
{
  return preg_match('/&#10[78]\d/', mb_encode_numericentity($content, array(0x0, 0x2FFFF, 0, 0xFFFF), 'UTF-8'));
}
```

thus no warranty, no any of the kind - but it may help you out (basically it encodes all foreign entities then checks for common cyrillic chars)

Best!

Answer (score 2):

I would download the Russian alphabet and then check the input string with `strstr()`. For example:

```
$russianChars = array('з', 'я'.. etc);

foreach($russianChars as $char) {
    if(strstr($input, $char)) {
        // russian char found in input, do something
    }
}
```

A good algorithm would probably do something after finding 3 Russian chars or so, to be sure that the language is actually Russian (since Russian chars may show up in other languages, I suggest doing some research if that's the case).

Answer (score 1):

SOURCE: http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Convert_cyrillic_to_latin_in_PHP-vWz

```
function ru2lat($str)    {
    $tr = array(
    "А"=>"a", "Б"=>"b", "В"=>"v", "Г"=>"g", "Д"=>"d",
    "Е"=>"e", "Ё"=>"yo", "Ж"=>"zh", "З"=>"z", "И"=>"i", 
    "Й"=>"j", "К"=>"k", "Л"=>"l", "М"=>"m", "Н"=>"n", 
    "О"=>"o", "П"=>"p", "Р"=>"r", "С"=>"s", "Т"=>"t", 
    "У"=>"u", "Ф"=>"f", "Х"=>"kh", "Ц"=>"ts", "Ч"=>"ch", 
    "Ш"=>"sh", "Щ"=>"sch", "Ъ"=>"", "Ы"=>"y", "Ь"=>"", 
    "Э"=>"e", "Ю"=>"yu", "Я"=>"ya", "а"=>"a", "б"=>"b", 
    "в"=>"v", "г"=>"g", "д"=>"d", "е"=>"e", "ё"=>"yo", 
    "ж"=>"zh", "з"=>"z", "и"=>"i", "й"=>"j", "к"=>"k", 
    "л"=>"l", "м"=>"m", "н"=>"n", "о"=>"o", "п"=>"p", 
    "р"=>"r", "с"=>"s", "т"=>"t", "у"=>"u", "ф"=>"f", 
    "х"=>"kh", "ц"=>"ts", "ч"=>"ch", "ш"=>"sh", "щ"=>"sch", 
    "ъ"=>"", "ы"=>"y", "ь"=>"", "э"=>"e", "ю"=>"yu", 
    "я"=>"ya", " "=>"-", "."=>"", ","=>"", "/"=>"-",  
    ":"=>"", ";"=>"","—"=>"", "–"=>"-"
    );
    return strtr($str,$tr);
}
```

then

```
echo ru2lat( "текст по-русски");  -------------->   "tekst po-russki"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an input for your description called description like this :

```
   <input name="description"/>
```

Add a condition in your mailer file like phpmailer or other like this :

```
if (preg_match("/[А-Яа-яЁё]/u", $_POST['description'])) {
  echo "Sorry, no russian description allowed";
  die();
  }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little unrelated to php, but I had a similar problem with spam from a contact form. If your site is behind [Cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com/), then you can limit the spam by checking what country the request is coming from. You can then flag it as potential spam and verify later if it is publishable.

I eventually started to mark as spam everything that came from a different country than mine, and I take a quick look to see if there is anything valuable there, and delete the rest. I also return the information to the potential spammer that he solved the recaptcha incorrectly, although it was solved correctly. With time the number of spam messages dropped significantly.

Cloudflare returns the country code in the header and this value is available in the `$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY']` variable.